# react-router does not work in production and surge deployments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My react application is working fine on localhost but when after i deployed it in gh-pages or surge it does not give me to move among pages using URL.

- This is the project repo [link](https://github.com/fossasia/chat.susi.ai)
- Demo url [here](http://chat.susi.ai/)

users can go to signup page by clicking menuItem of top right corner. but If user use http://chat.susi.ai/signup/ URL, it gives 404 page

I tried several solutions from internet but didn't work.

Next question is : I created a 404 page to show up when user tries to move to broken links.It works fine in localhost. but not in production. I tried [this](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1765) solution but nothing changed.

this is part of my index.js file

```
const App = () => (
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <MuiThemeProvider>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={ChatApp} />
                <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
                <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
                <Route exact path="/forgotpwd" component={ForgotPassword} />
                <Route exact path="*" component={NotFound} />

            </Switch>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

If someone can suggest good solution with sample code for my problems that would be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is happening because users aren't being served the `index.html` which bootstraps your app when they visit those URLs directly.

For surge, you can [add a `200.html` file](https://surge.sh/help/adding-a-200-page-for-client-side-routing) which contains the same contents as the `index.html` you're deploying (or just rename it to `200.html`) - this will then be served to users at any URL they visit which doesn't correspond to a static file, allowing your app to start running.

---

Edit: looks like you're using `create-react-app`. This works when you're developing locally because `create-react-app`'s `react-scripts` package handles serving your `index.html` as a fallback for these requests.

The [`react-scripts` user guide](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#readme) has sections on [how to handle this when deploying to GitHub Pages](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#notes-on-client-side-routing) and [surge.sh](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#surge) (as above).

Comment: indeed, serving the index.html file when visiting the subpath works fine :-)

Comment: https://medium.com/superhighfives/serving-client-side-routing-with-surge-sh-7b705542cf3

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me, but @NisugaJayawardana link did.

Comment: it does not work for me for angular.

Comment: For `serve`, use `$ serve -s {folder}` to default to index.html

Answer (score 29):

Changing `.htaccess` file in the case of using `apache` as the web server in your build folder worked for me:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: From: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing

Comment: do we put the .htaccess file in the build folder?

Comment: Yes. add the `.htaccess` where your `index.html` resides

Answer (score 7):

This issue happens on all single page applications (e.g. react, angular).
Follow below steps to resolve (only 4 surge):

1. `npm run build`
2. `cd build`
3. `cp index.html 200.html`
4. `surge`

Comment: what the step 4 `surge` do? I got `bash: surge: command not found`

Comment: Use npx surge  to fix bash: surge: command not found

Comment: I am using 
FROM httpd:2.4-alpine
COPY ./dist/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/

But it is not working I have also added .htaccess file still problem persists

Answer (score 4):

When deploying the build on static servers, in our React App if we would have used routers that use the `HTML5 pushState history API` under the hood (for example, React Router with `browserHistory`), the static file servers might fail to load the routes and appropriate screens and show up `404 - Not Found` error.

As described in the `create-react-app` [Deployment article](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment):

> when there is a fresh page load for a path for ex: `/todos/42`, the server looks for the file `build/todos/42` and does not find it. The server needs to be configured to respond to a request to `/todos/42` by serving `index.html`

So to make the routes working when using `Node` with `Express`, one can add configure the server `index.js` as below:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

// PATH CONFIGURATION TO RESPOND TO A REQUEST TO STATIC ROUTE REQUEST BY SERVING index.html
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(5000);
console.log('Server is listening on http://localhost:5000');
```

If you’re using **Apache HTTP Server**, you need to create a `.htaccess` file **in the `public` folder of your React APP** that looks like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

It will get copied to the `build` folder when you run `npm run build`.

Comment: HI @Rahul gupta, I'm using nginx server, where should I add similar fixes?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. And i solved it very easily... :)

I used react at my front-end(Create-React-App) and an express backend.
In dev mode all things works great but when i switched to the production build there was some routing issues in my react routing. After a long survey i found that the problem is on the server side serving up the index.html file.

It should be after all the server side routing but before all the app.post handler. In other words the following line should be placed after all `app.gets` and before all `app.posts`

```
// PRODUCTION
App.get('*', (req, res)=>{
res.sendFile(path.resolve(where, the, index.html, is))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem  and I solved it by taking advantage of `.htaccess` file.
I added a redirect that goes back to `index.html`, it does keep the url path and everything works perfectly.

My `.htaccess` file only has this line `ErrorDocument 404 /index.html` it must be on the root directory, create it if doesn't existing or overwrite the exist one.
I recommend you handle 404 inside your App.

I got this idea from https://medium.com/designer-recipes/how-to-make-a-custom-404-error-page-for-your-website-1af37a8b20d1

Answer (score 1):

If you deploy with Render.com you can fix it by adding

- Source: /*
- Destination: /index.html
- Action: Rewrite

to the Rewrite-config, see
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/handling-react-routing-in-production

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still having the same issue, You just have to wrap it with HashBrowser instead of BrowserRouter. I refer to this post https://muffinman.io/blog/react-router-subfolder-on-server/

Answer (score 0):

just add 200.html

inside 200.html

`<script src="path of your App.js"></script>`

it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

try to add `<base>` HTML tag in inside `<head></head>`
with `/` or deployment domain/subdomain name

either

```
<base href="/">
```

or

```
<base href="https://your-domain-or-subdomain-or-route-path.com/">
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to mention exect file of the entry point of html in the following way

**Error:**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
```

**Solution:**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Nginx you could redirect error page to index

```
on /etc/nginx/sites-available/default   [or your domain file]

server { 
 ...
 error_page 404 /index.html;
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it differently today because all of the answers currently posted not solved my problem.

The idea is

1. Java redirect "/test" url to "/url=test" because react only exists in root(/).
2. React reads url parameter and redirects "/url=test" to "/test".

Server side:

```java
package controller.error;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class HandleErrorController implements ErrorController {
    private static final String PATH = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("handleError");

        Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);
        //for brevity, only handling 404
        if (status != null && status.toString().equals("404")) {
            String referer = (String)request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
            String urlParam = referer != null && referer.startsWith("/") ? "?url=" + referer.substring(1) : "";
            response.sendRedirect("/" + urlParam);
            return null;
        }
        return "error";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return PATH;
    }
}
```

Client side:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Routes, Link, useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Main = ({ isTest }) => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        const param = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
        const url = param.get("url");
        if (url) {
            console.log(`navigate to ${url}`);
            navigate(`/${url}`, { replace: true });
        }
    }, [location.search, navigate]);

    return (
        <>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<AuthRoute />}>
                    <Route path="*" element={<SomePage />} />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </>
    );
};

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem for NGINX server, with simple solution by editing NGINX configuration for location like this:

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ **/index.html** =404;
    }
```

Adding "/index.html" to this line fixed the routing issue without .htaccess file or any other code changes.