# React router doesn't route traffic when hosted on firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

So this is pretty much just the product of creat-react-app and firbase init. It works exactly as expected when I do npm start but when I upload the package to firebase, the only page I am able to hit is at the / path. Even if I switch the components, they one on the / path will be hit.

App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Ok from './Ok';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./Home";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
            <main>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/ok" component={Ok}/>
                </Switch>
            </main>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>), document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Directory structure

```
.
├── build
│   ├── asset-manifest.json
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── manifest.json
│   ├── precache-manifest.ecdffa8fba4446ec939aeb81deef8a46.js
│   ├── service-worker.js
│   └── static
│       ├── css
│       │   ├── main.62e37b1d.chunk.css
│       │   └── main.62e37b1d.chunk.css.map
│       ├── js
│       │   ├── 1.c86c31d4.chunk.js
│       │   ├── 1.c86c31d4.chunk.js.map
│       │   ├── main.68e18920.chunk.js
│       │   ├── main.68e18920.chunk.js.map
│       │   ├── runtime~main.229c360f.js
│       │   └── runtime~main.229c360f.js.map
│       └── media
│           └── logo.5d5d9eef.svg
├── firebase.json
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   └── manifest.json
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── Home.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── logo.svg
    ├── Ok.js
    └── serviceWorker.js
```

ANSWER:

I removed the main tag from App.js and moved the BrowserRouter from index.js to App.js, wrapping the Switch tag with it

Comment: Does the `Ok` component exist? where's the code?

Comment: I think this is expected based on the fact that the Router is working on client side only. If you need to render server side, you could use something like react snap (https://github.com/stereobooster/react-snap) as an easy solution, otherwise you'll need to setup server rendering for your routes. Take a look here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491184/react-router-does-not-work-in-production-and-surge-deployments) at the accepted answer. I think this may be your problem

Comment: Ok component does exist.

Comment: Jordan, I'm trying to implement this but a little confused. I thought the Router was designed for SPA navigation. What do you mean it's only client side?

Answer (score 19):

You need to make sure the rewrites are enabled in your Firebase hosting configuration to redirect all requests to your index.html file. This assumes you are using create-react-app:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {"source": "/service-worker.js", "headers": [{"key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache"}]}
    ]
  }
}
```

The `init` command for Firebase actually provides this is an option when creating a project.

You will need to redeploy `firebase deploy` to propagate the changes.

**Update:** With the aforementioned `firebase.json` hosting configuration the following `index.js` and `App.js`, I was able to successfully deploy a `create-react-app` with working `react-router-dom` routing using `npm run build` following by `firebase deploy`.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(<Router><App /></Router>, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';

const Home = () => <h1>Home</h1>;
const Ok = () => <h1>Ok</h1>;

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/ok">Ok</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </header>
        <main>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/ok" component={Ok} />
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I tried this with no luck, but I'm not sure if maybe my directory structure is screwed up. ive added it to the question

Comment: Yeah it may other things but SPA navigation will not work on Firebase Hosting with that configuration

Comment: could you take a look, I think my index.html might be in the wrong place?

Comment: @DavidMassey I added a `App.js` and an `index.js` from a `create-react-app` used with the previously mentioned `firebase.json` configuration. I was successfully able to deploy the application using `npm run build` and `firebase deploy` and it routes successfully [link](https://sample-react-router-01.firebaseapp.com/). Try using the provided code, re-build and re-deploy and see if it makes a difference. If it does, it means something is wrong in your code. Your built structure is fine from what I can see.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderStaroselsky, I've been trying to implement your answer in my app, but with no luck. Could you have a look at the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61154061/react-and-firebase-routing-issue-blank-screen?noredirect=1#comment108187818_61154061)?

Comment: This works.... and don't worry about 'redirect all to your index page', it will actually work with the routes correctly at that point.  Worked for me today.

Answer (score 1):

by only modifying my `firebase.json` to include

```json
"rewrites": [
    {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
    }
]
```

my firebase hosted site shows routes properly.