# React and Firebase routing issue- blank screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router, react-router-dom

I am having an issue when deploying my React application to Firebase. The `"/"` route returns a blank page as shown here:

[image]

The `"/play"` route is working when deployed.

The application works locally, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52939427/react-router-doesnt-route-traffic-when-hosted-on-firebase) old post is very similar. I think the problem is related to how the Routing is set up.

**Index.json:**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
import "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
import Landing from "./Landing";
import Startpage from "./Startpage/Startpage";

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./Reducers/Reducers";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import promiseMiddleware from "redux-promise";
import { compose } from "redux";

import thunk from "redux-thunk";
const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

function configureStore(preloadedState) {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk, promiseMiddleware))
  );
}
const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Landing />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**Landing.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import App from "./App";
import Rules from "./Rules/Rules";
import { Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Startpage from "./Startpage/Startpage";
import history from "./history.js";

class Landing extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Startpage} />
          <Route exact path="/rules" component={Rules} />
          <Route exact path="/play" component={App} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default Landing;
```

**Startpage.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Startpage.css";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { compose } from "redux";
import { setGameId, setGameId1, updateState } from "../Actions/Actions";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { DB_CONFIG } from "../Config/config";
import history from "../history.js";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    width: "25ch",
  },
}));

class Startpage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      gameObj: { key: null, gameId: null },
      testing: false,
      newWordContent: "",
    };
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      firebase.initializeApp(DB_CONFIG);
    }
    firebase.database.enableLogging(false);

    this.gameIds = firebase.database().ref().child("gameIds");
  }
  getLargestGameIdInDb = () => {
    var myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.gameIds
        .orderByChild("gameId")
        .limitToLast(1)
        .once("value", function (snap) {
          snap.forEach((child) => {
            let filteredObj = child.val().gameId;
            console.log(child.val().gameId);
            resolve(filteredObj);
          });
        });
    });
    return myPromise;
  };

  handleNewGame = async () => {
    // Function fired when new game button is pressed!
    let a = await this.checkIfEmptyDb();
    if (a === false) {
      this.sendNew(0, this.handleState); // setting the new game id to 0.
    }
    if (a === true) {
      console.log("The db exists!");
      try {
        this.updateAndSendNew(this.sendNew);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("Make sure word is filled in");
      }
    }
  };

  checkIfEmptyDb = async () => {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("gameIds");
    // Return value of the promise
    return ref.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
      const a = snapshot.exists();
      return a;
    });
  };

  // callback func
  updateAndSendNew = async (callback) => {
    this.getLargestGameIdInDb().then((newId) => {
      let newGameId = newId + 1; // adding one to the larges gameId in the db
      callback(newGameId, this.handleState);
    });
  };
  sendNew = async (newId, callback) => {
    await callback(newId); // This is completed first before routing to the playing app.
    //this.routingFunction();
  };
  handleState = async (newId) => {
    try {
      var newRef = this.gameIds.push();
      var newKey = newRef.key;
      console.log(newKey, newId);
      newRef.set({ gameId: newId }).then(() => {
        console.log("add to redux state!");
        this.props.changeGlobalId2(newId, newKey); // updating store, is slow.
        this.setState(
          {
            testing: true,
            gameObj: {
              gameId: newId,
              key: newKey,
            },
          },
          () => {
            console.log("New state:", this.state);
          }
        );
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Game update not pushed to firebase");
    }
  };

  // I need to make sure this one is called after all those other ones!
  routingFunction = () => {
    this.props.history.push("/play");
  };
  handleUserInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({ newWordContent: e.target.value });
  };
  joinGame = () => {
    console.log(this.state.newWordContent); // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch
    this.getMatchingGameKey(this.state.newWordContent)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("key", res.key);
        console.log("gameId", res.val().gameId);
        this.setState({ newWordContent: "" });
        this.props.changeGlobalId2(res.val().gameId, res.key); // update redux state.
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Game ID does not exist in db.
        alert("Game PIN does not exist ");
      });

    // compare the gameID with the db
  };
  getMatchingGameKey = (gameId) => {
    var myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      //let ref = firebase.database().ref().child("gameIds").child("gameId");
      this.gameIds
        .orderByChild("gameId")
        .equalTo(parseInt(gameId, 10))
        .on("value", function (snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.val() == null) {
            reject(Error("GameId does not exist!"));
          } else {
            snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
              resolve(data); // passing on
              //console.log(data.key);
            });
          }
        });
    });
    return myPromise;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div>
          <header className="main-header">
            <div className="container">
              <h1 className="mh-logo">Chapi-chapau</h1>
              <nav className="main-nav">
                <ul className="main-nav-list"></ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </header>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="join">
            <div>Join existing game</div>
            <div className="column">
              <TextField
                id="outlined-full-width"
                value={this.state.newWordContent}
                style={{ margin: 8 }}
                placeholder="GAME PIN + ENTER"
                helperText="Full width!"
                margin="normal"
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true,
                }}
                variant="outlined"
                onChange={this.handleUserInput}
              />
              <Button
                id="outlined-button"
                variant="outlined"
                onClick={this.joinGame}
              >
                Join game
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="new">
            <div>Generate new game pin</div>
            <Button
              id="outlined-button"
              variant="outlined"
              onClick={this.handleNewGame}
            >
              Create game PIN
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log("mapStateToProps", state);
  return {
    globalGameId: state.globalGameId,
    globalGameKey: state.globalGameKey,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    changeGlobalId2: (id, gameKey) => {
      dispatch(updateState(id, gameKey)).then(() => {
        history.push("/play");
      });
    },
  };
}

export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps))(Startpage);
```

**firebase.json:**

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {"source": "/service-worker.js", "headers": [{"key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache"}]}
    ]
  }
}
```

**Project structure:**

```
.
├── README.md
├── build
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── asset-manifest.json
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── logo192.png
│   ├── logo512.png
│   ├── manifest.json
│   ├── precache-manifest.854d50eae40e11026f38a5efaaf2e505.js
│   ├── robots.txt
│   ├── service-worker.js
│   └── static
├── database.rules.json
├── firebase.json
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── logo192.png
│   ├── logo512.png
│   ├── manifest.json
│   └── robots.txt
├── src
│   ├── Actions
│   ├── App.css
│   ├── App.js
│   ├── App.test.js
│   ├── Config
│   ├── Images
│   ├── Landing.js
│   ├── Modal
│   ├── Navbar
│   ├── Reducers
│   ├── Rules
│   ├── Startpage
│   ├── Word
│   ├── WordForm
│   ├── Wordpool
│   ├── history.js
│   ├── index.css
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── logo.svg
│   ├── serviceWorker.js
│   └── setupTests.js
└── yarn.lock
```

Output after building:

```
The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
```

**History.js**

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();
export default history;
```

Thanks!

Comment: check this if it is useful .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486069/firebase-not-running-index-html-file

Comment: @gdh thanks for the response, but I already changed  ```"public": "build"```.It is deployed successfully, but with the blank starting page.

Comment: There looks to be an issue with your `react-router-dom` imports. You are importing `Router`, but your probably want `BrowserRouter` instead. Change the import to `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";`

Comment: I will give that a go. The reason I did that instead was to be able to use the ```history.js``` file for setting ```history.push('/play')``` [outside the component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153517/how-to-access-history-object-outside-of-a-react-component). I will add history.js now to the question.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky the problem is still there unfortunately. Was not working in dev with BrowserRouter as Router .. :/