# Error when reloading website in production developed with react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .htaccess, react-router

Currently I have developed a site with `react js` and I have used `react-router-dom` for the routes, when I run the command npm run build to get the project ready for production I find several inconsistencies when I try to leave the site running in a subdirectory using xampp, the inconsistencies are as follows

1. When I put a path in the browser that is different from the root path the browser, for example `localhost:8085/pruebaDev/viewusers/` it returns the following:

Object not located! The requested URL could not be located on this server. If you have entered the URL manually, please check your spelling and try again.

2. When I put only initial path of the subdirectory it loads without any problem, example `localhost:8085/pruebaDev/`

The configurations that I have made are the following

**.htaccess configuration**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pruebaDev/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

**package.json File**

```
  "homepage": ".",
  "name": "pruebaDev",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "sweetalert2": "^10.9.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Configuration file of the routes App.js**

```
<Router basename={'/pruebaDev/'}>
  ...
</Router>
```

Comment: what is the error you see in the browser console?

Comment: This is the error => Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53294427/8393975